# Mongodb Shard key with Multiple fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, sharding

I am having the large collection having the below document structure.I also created the one unique index and one compound index.Now I need to enable sharding on this collection.

In this case, how can I assign the shard key for fast read performance on the sharding environment.I am also going to do multiple write operation simultaneously. Is it possible to use the shard key as my available unique index?

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54fdf0540cf26047a823e123"),
        "height" : 15,
        "sheetname" : "Test Sheet",
        "width" : 225,
        "value" : "Test",
        "bottom" : 14,
        "column" : 1,
        "left" : 0,
        "right" : 224,
        "row" : 1,
        "top" : 0,
        "bookid" : ObjectId("54fdf0537a0a58734f11aa17")
}
```

My Indexes are:

```
{
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "bookid" : 1,
                        "sheetname" : 1,
                        "top" : 1,
                        "bottom" : 1,
                        "column" : 1
                },
                "name" : "bookid_1_sheetname_1_top_1_bottom_1_column_1",
                "ns" : "abc.test",
                "safe" : true
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "unique" : true,
                "key" : {
                        "bookid" : 1,
                        "sheetname" : 1,
                        "row" : 1,
                        "column" : 1
                },
                "name" : "bookid_1_sheetname_1_row_1_column_1",
                "ns" : "abc.test",
                "safe" : true
        }
```